# Compare two arrays ignoring only start element

Tags: java

I have to compare if two arrays are equal ignoring only the first element. Is it possible to achieve the same without iterating

Comment: arrays of what? I bet you need iterating

Comment: Without iterating through the array, can you access all of its elements?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Arrays.copyOfRange()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) to get the subarrays and [`Arrays.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29) to perform the equality check.

Note that though there is no explicit iterating - there is iteration behind the scenes.

Code snap:

```
int arr1[] = { 1,2,3,4 };
int arr2[] = { 0,2,3,4 };
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(
        Arrays.copyOfRange(arr1, 1, arr1.length), 
        Arrays.copyOfRange(arr2, 1, arr2.length)));
```

Comment: +1 This will iterate three times of course.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you try, in order to check two arrays for equality, you have to check each and every element.For that, you have to access all the elements by iterating through array.Even though, you can avoid doing this manually by using some inbuilt functions, same logic happens behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Let's assume your two arrays are named A and B.

1. Create array C that consists of all elements from A except for the
   first one
   ( `System.arraycopy(A, 1, C, 0, A.length();` ).
2. Create array D that consists of all elements from B except for the first one.
3. Call `Arrays.equals()` to compare C and D.

Also, keep in mind Renjiths point.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] array1 = {"hi","hi2"};
List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array1));

String[] array2 = {"hi3","hi2"};
List<String> temp2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array2));

boolean condition = temp.subList(1, temp.size()).equals(temp2.subList(1, temp2.size()));
```

As already pointed out by amit **there is iteration behind the scenes**

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.equals(Arrays.asList(array1).subList(1, array1.length), Arrays.asList(array2).subList(1, array2.length));
```

Arrays.equals will use a loop though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you (or method you call) will have to iterate through those arrays since array is not an object and doesn't have equals method.

Operator == compares values only in case of primitive types, it compares pointers (memory addresses) in other cases. That means you would get true only if both arrays are one and the same, if the arrays were two separate yet identical arrays, you would get false.

Copying a part of arrays and comparing them will result in multiple iterations through arrays, even it might not be obvious. (Getting subarray of both arrays contain at least 1 iteration each, comparing them another one.)

That said you can use 1 cycle to iterate through arrays and compare values one by one, starting with index 1 to skip first element. Replace Object type paramter with your array's type in the following code:

```
private boolean compareMyArrays(Object[] array1, Object[] array2) {
    if ((array1 == null) && (array2 == null)) {
        return true;
    }

    if ((array1 == null) || (array2 == null)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (array1.length != array2.length) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < array1.lenght; i++) {
        if ( !array1[i].equals(array2[i]) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps.